# Conceptual differences with REST on Flask

Tags: python, rest, api, flask, flask-restful

Well, I'm doing a REST API with Flask and, when making different branches of the API, I'm having a doubt:
What's, conceptually, the difference between:

```
@app.route('/do_anything', methods=['GET', 'POST']
def do_anything():
    foo = 'Str example'
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        foo = flask.request.form['foo']
    return foo
```

from Flask, and:

```
class Do_anything(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'Str example'
    def get(self):
        return self.foo
    def post(self):
        self.foo = flask.request.form['foo']
        return self.foo

api.add_resource(Do_anything, '/do_anything')
```

from Flask-RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is easier to maintain, test and expand your code when using Flask-RESTful (OOP) approach. Flask itself is a micro-framework, which means it is not fully featured framework. That's why there are extensions which allows to customise your code.
Every time you want to make sth big, go for OOP approach. Otherwise choose the one that suits you the most.

Comment: Yes, I think that too (It's easier, faster and better in general to use Flask_RESTful), but conceptually them, in (for example) the lines I've posted are the same? Or there is any difference (outside of their immediate functional differences)?